# How to make facebook access token invalid?

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have a non-expiring facebook access token for my app. Unfortunately, this token was published on a public side. Is there any way to make this token invalid so that nobody can access the data?

I could not find any settings in my facebook app that shows me how to delete this specific token.

Comment: What _type_ of token? Page tokens should get invalidated when you remove the relevant permissions from the user account that was used to fetch the page token. (Or when that user changes their account password.) If this is about the app token, then I think you need to reset your app secret via the app dashboard. (And then of course update any server-side code, that uses this secret.)

Comment: The type of the token is ``page access token``. I was the one who created it with my ``user access token``. I changed my password for my facebook account one hour ago, but I can still use the page access token. Additionally, I tried to remove the relevant permissions from my user account. However, if I run ``me/permissions`` in Graph API I get the message: ``"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (permissions) on node type (Page)"``

Comment: You’d need to call `me/permissions` with your user token, not the page token.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to work!